# How to create a script that would calculate the difference between samples in a list?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a script that would calculate the difference between samples in a list.
If we take this example:

```
 - result1 = 33
 - result2 = 45
 - result3 = 66
 - result4 = 47
 - result"n" = 50
```

The calculus should start at the second result from the list and descend until the last result, and then sum up those results:

```
result2 - result1 = 12,  
result3 - result2 = 21,  
result4 - result3 = 19,    
result"n" - result4= 3  
sum = 12 + 21 + 19 + 3 = 55
```

I am new at scripting, and so far i only came up with this solution:

```
$numbers 
$1=[math]::abs($numbers[0]-$numbers[1])
$2=[math]::abs($numbers[1]-$numbers[2])
$3=[math]::abs($numbers[2]-$numbers[3])
$4=[math]::abs($numbers[3]-$numbers[4])
write-host "the results = $1, $2, $3, $4"
$sum = $1 + $2 + $3 + $4
```

The problem is that the list is dynamic and changes in length, one time there are 10 results and one time 20 for example.
I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587104/calculate-the-difference-between-consecutive-grouped-columns-in-a-data-table), but i don't know how to implement the solution to my case, as that is too complicated for me.

Comment: result4 - result3 = -19, not 19. I'm gathering you want the absolute value of the difference, but, depending on what you're trying to do, choosing absolute value of difference vs just the difference could make a big difference (pun intended).

Comment: yes, user2460798, you are right, i forgot to mention that i need absolute values of difference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for loop, use the length of your `$numbers` array to know when to stop.

```
$numbers = @(33,45,66,47,50)
$sum = 0
for($cur=1;$cur -lt $numbers.Length; $cur += 1){
    $sum += [math]::abs($numbers[$cur]-$numbers[$cur-1]);
}
$sum
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a `For` loop. It is structured as such:

```
For(<initial declaration, usually a start point like $i = 0>; <Condition to stop when false>;<Action to perform on each iteration to progress loop>){
    Code to perform on each loop
}
```

For you we would do something like:

```
For($i=1;$i -le $numbers.count;$i++)
```

That starts 1, and since arrays start at 0 this will get you going with the second record. Then in the scriptblock we do something like:

```
{
    [array]$Results += [math]::abs($numbers[$i] - $numbers[($i-1)])
}
```

That will get the differences for you, then to display them you can do something like:

```
"the results = " + ($Results -join ", ")
$sum = $Results|Measure -sum|select -expand Sum
```

So you put that all together and get

```
For($i=1;$i -le $numbers.count;$i++){
    [array]$Results += [math]::abs($numbers[$i] - $numbers[($i-1)])
}
"the results = " + ($Results -join ", ")
$sum = $Results|Measure -sum|select -expand Sum
```