# How to calculate the difference between consecutive sets of two columns in a column range using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to calculate the difference between consecutive columns in a range of columns using dplyr.

For example, using the **iris** data set I would want to be able to specify the range **Sepal.Width:Petal.Width** and have a dataframe that contained the original **iris** data and the differences between the consecutive columns from Sepal.Width:Petal.Width:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species diff1 diff2
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa   2.1   1.2
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa   1.6   1.2
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa   1.9   1.1
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa   1.6   1.3
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa   2.2   1.2
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa   2.2   1.3
```

Someone posted a solution loops and lapply ([Calculate the difference between consecutive, grouped columns in a data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587104/calculate-the-difference-between-consecutive-grouped-columns-in-a-data-table)) but I'm specifically looking for a dplyr solution.

Comment: The specified range starts with Sepal.Width, so the first difference is 3.5 - 1.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a less advanced approach using `dplyr` and `tidyr` verbs. First I gather the columns for differencing into long format, then take their differences vs. previous column, strip out NA's for the first columns which have no previous column, rename the column, spread out, and attach onto the original.

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>%
  bind_cols(iris %>%
    rowid_to_column() %>%
    gather(col, val, Sepal.Width:Petal.Width) %>%
    group_by(rowid) %>%
    mutate(val = abs(val - lag(val))) %>%
    filter(!is.na(val)) %>%
    mutate(col = paste0("diff_", col)) %>%
    spread(col, val)  %>%
    select(contains("diff"))
  )


    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species rowid diff_Petal.Length diff_Petal.Width
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa     1               2.1              1.2
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa     2               1.6              1.2
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa     3               1.9              1.1
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa     4               1.6              1.3
5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa     5               2.2              1.2
6            5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     setosa     6               2.2              1.3
7            4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3     setosa     7               2.0              1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`.  We `select` the range of columns, remove the first and last column in to a `list` of data.frames, then use `reduce` to get the difference between set of equal dimension datasets, and rename the columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
out <- iris %>%
      select(Sepal.Width:Petal.Width) %>% 
      {list(.[-length(.)], .[-1])} %>% 
      reduce(`-`) %>% 
      rename_all(~ str_c("diff", seq_along(.))) %>% 
      bind_cols(iris, .)

head(out)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species diff1 diff2
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa   2.1   1.2
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa   1.6   1.2
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa   1.9   1.1
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa   1.6   1.3
#5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa   2.2   1.2
#6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa   2.2   1.3
```

---

Or another approach is to loop through index of columns `select` the columns, `reduce` it to a single column with `-` and bind with the original dataset

```
map_dfc(3:4, ~ iris %>%
                select(.x-1, .x) %>% 
                transmute(diff = reduce(., `-`))) %>% 
     bind_cols(iris, .)
```

Comment: Would you consider listing the specific packages needed here? It looks like `dplyr`, `purrr`, and `stringr`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `grepl` and `which` to get the column indices..

```
start <- which(grepl("Sepal.Width", colnames(iris)))
end <- which(grepl("Petal.Width", colnames(iris)))

for (i in start:(end-1)) {
eval(parse(text = paste0("iris$diff",i-1," <- iris[,",i,"]-iris[,",i,"+1]")))
}
```

Comment: thanks @jgjiggle but I was looking for a dplyr solution